# Convert unicode characters with c#

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a client who has asked us to write a c# application that takes data from their database and output it to a .csv file.  So far so good.

This DB contains some unicode characters and when the client opens up the .csv with Excel those characters look "weird".  Ex:  x0096 looks like an A with a carrot on top next to the Euro currency sign, when the client thinks it should look like a Dash.

So I have been asked to make those characters look "not wierd".

I have written code for each weird character (I have like 12 of the below lines).

```
input = input.Replace((char)weirdCharacter, (char)normalCharacter);
```

There has got to be a better way.

Comment: So what encoding are the database and CSV file using?

Comment: The first thought is to make an array of weird and normal characters, and loop through it (rather than one line per...). But it's still a bit kluge-ey.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Can your answer be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net

Comment: Yeah.  It was an encoding issue.  I used a solution similar to what VJ mentioned below.  The link that Floris mentioned had some code that was useful too.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I was generating HTML files.  The solution for me was to change the encoding of my output file.

```
StreamWriter swHTMLPage = 
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(OutputFileName, false, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Once I added the Encoding.UTF8 parameter the characters started displaying correctly.  I don't know if this can be applied to your solution though since Excel is involved, but I am betting it can be.

Comment: Assuming that the database uses UTF-8 throughout, this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As Vincent James says, if this is an encoding issue, then the ideal way to fix this is to just use the right encoding when you decode/encode the value, but if that still doesn't work...

I think this is pretty straightforward.  What do you think?:

```
Dictionary<char, char> substitutions = new Dictionary<char, char> {
  {'\0x0096', 'F'}, {'\0x0101', 'O'}, {'\0x0121', 'O'}, ...
};

foreach(KeyValuePair<char, char> pair in substitutions)
{
   input.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```